# A function to print prototype chain for a given object

Tags: javascript

Sometimes I get lost in `prototype` chain of my JavaScript objects, so I would like to have a function that would print in a friendly way the prototype chain of a given object.

I am using Node.js.

```
function getPrototypeChain(obj) {
   ....
}
var detail = getPrototypeChain(myobject)
console.log(JSON.stringify(detail))
```

Comment: maybe off-topic, you can use this tool to visualize the prototype chain in a graphed way: http://www.objectplayground.com/

Comment: have you tried jetbrains phpstorm with nodejs plugin?

Comment: @VladNikitin, nope, how you think it can be used here?

Comment: not sure that this will feet your needs , but with this tool you can set breakpoints and as result watch variables, so your variable will be displayed in comfortable gui (with prototype including)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This function shows prototype chain of any object clearly:

```js
function tracePrototypeChainOf(object) {

    var proto = object.constructor.prototype;
    var result = '';

    while (proto) {
        result += ' -> ' + proto.constructor.name + '.prototype';
        proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto)
    }
 
    result += ' -> null';
    return result;
}

var trace = tracePrototypeChainOf(document.body)
alert(trace);
```

`tracePrototypeChainOf(document.body)` returns `"-> HTMLBodyElement.prototype -> HTMLElement.prototype -> Element.prototype -> Node.prototype -> EventTarget.prototype -> Object.prototype -> null"`

Note: the `__proto__` of `document.body` is not `HTMLBodyElement`, it is `HTMLBodyElement.prototype`. `HTMLBodyElement`  is the constructor of `document.body`, i.e. a function.

The end of every prototype chain is `null`.

Answer (score 5):

You could use something like the following:

```
function printPrototype(obj, i) {
    var n = Number(i || 0);
    var indent = Array(2 + n).join("-");

    for(var key in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            console.log(indent, key, ": ", obj[key]);
        }
    }

    if(obj) {
        if(Object.getPrototypeOf) {
            printPrototype(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj), n + 1);
        } else if(obj.__proto__) {
            printPrototype(obj.__proto__, n + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5fv1tv1x/1/

Call it like so:

```
printPrototype(myObj);
```

It may require some modification to fit your exact needs. In node, you may also need some extra guards ( I tested in Chrome so I only needed to guard against 'obj' being undefined before recursing).

Answer (score 1):

```js
function protoChain(o) {
    var chain = [];
    (function protoChainImpl(o) {
        if (o == null) {
            return;
        }
        var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(o);
        if (proto) {
            chain.push(proto.hasOwnProperty('constructor') ? proto.constructor.name : 'undefined');
            return protoChainImpl(proto);
        }
    })(o);
    return chain;
}

class ExampleParent {}
class Example extends ExampleParent {}

document.write(
  'function(){}: ', protoChain(function() {}),
  '<br>',
  '[]: ', protoChain([]),
  '<br>',
  'Example: ', protoChain(new Example()),
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

fork of function from @Artem Devlysh (top on this answer) with can correctly handling object derived NULL

```
 function tracePrototypeChainOf(object) {
    var proto = null
     if (Object.getPrototypeOf(object) !== null) {
         var proto = object.constructor.prototype
    }
    let result = `${typeof object.name === 'undefined' ? '(.)' : '(' + object.name + ')'}`;
    if (proto === null) {
        return `${result} -> (null)`
    }
    else {
            while (proto) {
            result += ' -> ' + proto.constructor.name;
            proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto)
        }
        return result;
    }
 }
```