# Object made inside function won't work, but object being passed in does

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, gmail-api

Using `Google's Gmail API`, A module returns an `auth` object that I use in a `Gmail object` inside of my `listLabels`function. When It's passed in it works just fine, but If I try creating that exact same object inside of the function and use that in the `Gmail object` it returns out this (Separate GoogleAPIs module)

```
error:     req = authClient.request(options, callback);
                     ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'request'
```

This is what my function looks like right now:

```
function listLabels(auth) {
    var auth1 = {
        "transporter": {},
        "clientId_": "75i4354355NOTID.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "clientSecret_": "NOTSECRET",
        "redirectUri_": "http://notawebsite",
        "opts": {},
        "credentials": {
            "access_token": "not.not_access_token",
            "token_type": "Bearer",
            "expiry_data":1441095644613
        }

    }
        console.log("Original Auth: " + JSON.stringify(auth, null, 4));
        console.log("New Auth: " + JSON.stringify(auth1, null, 4));
        var gmail = google.gmail('v1');
        gmail.users.labels.list({
                auth: auth,
                userId: 'email@email.com',
        }, function(err, response) {
                if (err) {
                        console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
                        return;
                }
                var labels = response.labels;
                if (labels.length == 0) {
                        console.log('No labels found.');
                } else {
                        console.log('Labels:');
                        for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
                                var label = labels[i];
                                console.log('- %s', label.name);
                        }
                }
        });
}
```

If I use the `auth` object passed in it works just fine, if I use `auth1`it doesn't work and gives me the error above.

As you can see, I've also attempted to print out both objects below:

```
Original Auth: {
    "transporter": {},
    "clientId_": "...",
    "clientSecret_": "...",
    "redirectUri_": "...",
    "opts": {},
    "credentials": {
        "access_token": "...",
        "token_type": "Bearer",
        "expiry_date": 1441098460931
    }
}
New Auth: {
    "transporter": {},
    "clientId_": "...",
    "clientSecret_": "...",
    "redirectUri_": "...",
    "opts": {},
    "credentials": {
        "access_token": "...",
        "token_type": "Bearer",
        "expiry_data": 1441095644613
    }
}
```

(Both tokens are now expired)

When Auth is logged:

```
{ array: 
   [ { [Function: OAuth2Client]
       super_: [Function: AuthClient],
       GOOGLE_OAUTH2_AUTH_BASE_URL_: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
       GOOGLE_OAUTH2_TOKEN_URL_: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
       GOOGLE_OAUTH2_REVOKE_URL_: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke',
       GOOGLE_OAUTH2_FEDERATED_SIGNON_CERTS_URL_: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs',
       CLOCK_SKEW_SECS_: 300,
       MAX_TOKEN_LIFETIME_SECS_: 86400,
       ISSUER_: 'accounts.google.com' },
     [Function: AuthClient],
     [Function: Object] ],
  string: 'OAuth2Client :: AuthClient :: Object' }
```

Comment: Make a direct `console.log(auth)` and write here the result please. Also check for diffenrece between the methods of the 2 objects. Auth should now just be a simple json object, it should contain methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you're not printing the whole prototype chain. `console.log` doesn't do this by default, as far as I know. So the original `auth` has some prototype with the method `request`, and your "clone" doesn't. Hence the error.

Or perhaps you're simply printing it without methods somehow, and `auth` has the method `request` directly. But I think not printing the prototype is more likely.

Comment: How can I view the entire chain? Printing just `auth` directly shows [object Object]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168033/a-function-to-print-prototype-chain-for-a-given-object

Comment: When logging the chain, I see: (Check post)

Comment: I'm not sure you printed the right thing (or perhaps the answer to the print question is imperfect in some way), but you now can probably see the object is much more complicated. Recreating it from scratch without its' own source code will be hard.